# How can I create a 'sub-blog' which has its own sidebar on individual posts?

Tags: posts, categories, sidebar, blog

I've created a WordPress site with a blog which has several categories of posts. One category, 'News', is a special one, and should display separately ('News' posts will only ever be tagged as 'News' and not anything else).

So, on the blog page, I want to show all posts which are in any category apart from New. The sidebar should also list the same posts (i.e. exclude any which are 'News'). When an individual post is clicked on,  the page shown should have a sidebar with the same posts again.

The blog page is working fine, just using the regular WP functionality, with sidebar 'blog_default'.

On the News page, I want to show all posts which are in the category News. This time the side bar should show only 'News' posts. I got this working by creating a sidebar called 'news' and assigning it to the Category 'News' in the sidebar config page.  In the sidebar itself I added a widget which uses the 'posts in sidebar' plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-in-sidebar/) to get all posts with category 'News' and show them.

The issue I'm having is that when I go into a 'News' post, I want the sidebar to still show only the News posts.  I can do this by individually selecting each post in the sidebar configuration page, but this is a bit awkward and I know some people will forget to do it.  Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: We can't help you with that plugin, but if you ask instead about your original problem, then that can be answered and is actually easier to answer than fixing/automating the plugin. _**"How do I display a list of posts that have the same categories as the current post?"**_, the answer to that question may even allow you to eliminate a lot of sidebars

Comment: Sharon, you'd probably have to write a custom template for news or edit the theme's single.php template and use conditional checks then load different widget areas depending on the category.